Hilbert and Semantic Finitism
To what extent can Hilbert be considered a semantic finitist? Does he believe that infinitary statements are meaningless or does he present a framework to show that even if they were meaningless then the conclusions would still hold?

See Hilbert's Program

Hilbert was not exactly a semantic finitist in the modern sense because his idea of the finite relied on "extra-logical discrete objects, which exist intuitively as immediate experience before all thought". This invokes quasi-Kantian intuition and is closer to intuitionism than to strict finitism. Moreover, he accepts talk of infinities as meaningful in the spirit of fictionalism, "the transfinite axioms and formulae are adjoined to the finite axioms, just as in the theory of complex variables the imaginary elements are adjoined to the real." It is just that such talk is not referential.

The issue is not that of "belief": Hilbert clearly was a "supporter" of classical logic and mathematics of infinity (Cantor's set theory). Hilbert's Program was a project: to adopt mathematical tools (finitary arithmetic) that are acceptable to Intuitionism and use them to prove that formalized counterparts of arithmetic and analysis are consistent. Being "finitary", i.e. acceptable form an intuitive point of view (see @Conifold's remarks above wrt Kant), the proof will be "intuitionistically valid"; showing the consistency of "the math of infinity" they will legitimate their use.

At least three weak points: 1) from Brouwer point of view, the "formalized counterpart" of math is not "real” math; 2) Hilbert's point of view that consistency=reality is too much “formalistic" for Intuitionsim (but was so also for Frege); 3) the project was showed to be unfeasible (in the original strict sense of e.g. PRA) by Gödel's results.
